# Add a reference to a JavaScript file in a custom action for a provider hosted app

Tags: javascript, custom-actions, provider-hosted-app

I have a custom ribbon button in my app where I am trying to add logic to enable/disable the button based on whether or not the selected items are records. I am able to get the `EnabledScript` attribute to work, but I want to be able to debug the code I am running in it. I have tried to add a reference to a script file from my app like below

```
  <CustomAction Id="CustomAction.Scripts"
          Location="ScriptLink"
          ScriptSrc="~remoteAppWeb/Scripts/Record/Records.js"/>
```

However this is giving me the following **error**:

> The 'Location' attribute is invalid - The value 'ScriptLink' is invalid according to its datatype

The MSDN documentation is telling me that `location` has to be set to `ScriptLink` for `ScriptSrc` to be applicable [CustomAction Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460194.aspx)

Am I missing a step or can I not reference a script in a provider hosted app?

Comment: SharePoint online or on premise?

Comment: Its sharepoint premise

Comment: I have the same sht... I am tired of sharepoint... Havent seen such inconsistent system for long time